# ¿Cómo puedo hacer select de SQL a un select LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq

Esto es mi consulta EN SQL; por favor alguien me podrías dar la mano se le agradece

```
        Select HTAR_AcomodacionId, HOTA_Acomodacion, HTAR_CategoriaId,
        Categoria, HTAR_PrecioTar from HotTarifas,
        (Select HotCategoriasId, CAT_Cat1 as Categoria from HotCategorias 
            where HotCategoriasId       
        in ( SELECT HTAR_CategoriaId FROM HotTarifas       
                  Where HTAR_HotelID = 2 
                  and HTAR_AcomodacionId = 3))
           as NomCategoria, HotAcomodaciones 
           Where HTAR_CategoriaId         
        in (SELECT HTAR_CategoriaId FROM Hot
          Where HTAR_HotelID = 2
           and HTAR_AcomodacionId = 3)
           and HotCategoriasId = HTAR_CategoriaId
           and HotAcomodacionesId = HTAR_AcomodacionId
```

He intentado hacer de esta forma en LINQ pero aun no me sale

```
                var HotAcoCatPre = from hotcat in contexto.HotCategoria
                                   from hotaco in contexto.HotAcomodacion
                                   from hotar in contexto.HotTarifas
                                   where contexto.HotTarifas.Any(
                                        hotar => hotar.HTAR_HotelID == 2 &&
                                        hotar.HTAR_AcomodacionId == 3)
                                   where contexto.HotTarifas.Any(
                                       ht => ht.HTAR_HotelID == 2 &&                                           
                                       ht.HTAR_AcomodacionId == 3 &&
                                       ht.HTAR_CategoriaId == ht.HTAR_CategoriaId &&
                                       ht.HTAR_AcomodacionId == ht.HTAR_AcomodacionId
                                       )
                                   select new Item                                       
                                   {
                                       id = hotcat.HotCategoriasId,
                                       value = hotcat.CAT_Cat1,
                                       precio = hotar.HTAR_PrecioTar,
                                       ida = hotaco.HotAcomodacionesId,
                                       valuea = hotaco.HOTA_Acomodacion
                                   };       
                return HotAcoCatPre.ToList();
```

Comment: No te acomodaría crear un procedimiento almacenado y llamar a este procedimiento desde el código? Personalmente cuando las consultas incluyen más de dos tablas prefiero hacerlo de esta forma

Comment: ¿Usas EntityFramework?

Comment: Así es, si uso EntityFramework

Comment: ¿No te es más facil meter la consulta SQL en un procedimiento y actualizar el modelo de EF para traer ese procedimiento? Así sólo tendrías que inicializar el `DBContext` y llamar a tu procedimiento con los argumentos que necesites.

Comment: Cómo actualizo el modelo de EF

Comment: Puedes seguir [este link](https://blog.jongallant.com/2012/08/entity-framework-manual-update/), este [otro link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-and-update-an-edmx-file-using-entity-framework-data-model-in-visual-stud/) tambien hace el trabajo, espero te sirva :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar Database.ExecuteSqlCommand y pasar la consulta como tal.

Espero te sirva

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SQL QUERY AQUI");
}
```